# How do I update cupy/CUDA so that it works again and fixes my conda environment?

Tags: python, linux, anaconda, conda, cupy

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 (64 bit) and I was trying to use a function which uses cupy to resample some data, but received the error `AttributeError: type object 'cupy.core.core.Indexer' has no attribute '__reduce_cython__'`. I saw an [issue on github](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/4287) with the same error which suggested it was due to a version mismatch or missing dependency.

First I tried updating cupy with conda, but then when I tried to import cupy I'd get an error that cupy wasn't installed correctly and suggested to try `pip install cupy --no-cache-dir -vvvv` to fix it. This didn't seem to work and the folder in site-packages was called ~upy for some reason (there was a lot of output/errors as this command ran, but I'm not sure where it would have saved those messages).

I tried running `nvcc --version` as suggested in the issue to check my cuda version, but received an error that nvcc was an unrecognized command. I've previously had cupy/CUDA working, but I tried to update cuda with `sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit`. Now nvcc works and outputs `Cuda compilation tools, release 9.1, V9.1.85`. (Note that under /usr/local/cuda, the version.txt file says "CUDA Version 10.1.168".)

I was still getting errors, so I tried `sudo apt-get --purge remove "*cublas*" "*cufft*" "*curand*"  "*cusolver*" "*cusparse*" "*npp*" "*nvjpeg*" "cuda*" "nsight*"` and `conda uninstall cupy` to remove the files so I could start fresh, but then I learned about the `--revisions` argument for conda. Now I'm trying to go back to revision 11, but get the following output:

```
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are missing from the target environment:
  - conda-forge/linux-64::gnutls==3.6.13=h79a8f9a_0
  - conda-forge/linux-64::openh264==2.1.1=h8b12597_0
  - anaconda/linux-64::cupti==10.1.168=0
  - conda-forge/linux-64::openssl==1.1.1g=h516909a_0
  - anaconda/linux-64::cudnn==7.6.5=cuda10.1_0
  - anaconda/linux-64::tensorflow==2.2.0=gpu_py37h1a511ff_0
  - conda-forge/linux-64::ca-certificates==2020.6.20=hecda079_0
  - conda-forge/linux-64::conda==4.8.3=py37hc8dfbb8_1
  - anaconda/linux-64::tensorflow-base==2.2.0=gpu_py37h8a81be8_0
  - conda-forge/linux-64::nettle==3.4.1=h1bed415_1002
  - anaconda/linux-64::cupy==6.0.0=py37hc0ce245_0
  - anaconda/linux-64::cudatoolkit==10.1.243=h6bb024c_0
  - anaconda/linux-64::_tflow_select==2.1.0=gpu
  - conda-forge/linux-64::lame==3.100=h14c3975_1001
```

Before I break things further, any suggestions on how I should fix this? My software updater is now giving me [an error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8jYj.png) that says the package system is broken.

```
Check if you are using third party repositories. If so disable them, since they are a common source of problems.
Furthermore run the following command in a Terminal: apt-get install -f
Transaction failed: The package system is broken, with the rest of the message as follows:
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:

nvidia-cuda-toolkit: Depends: nvidia-profiler (= 9.1.85-3ubuntu1) but 9.1.85-3ubuntu1 is installed
                     Depends: nvidia-cuda-dev (= 9.1.85-3ubuntu1) but it is not installed
                     Depends: opencl-dev but it is a virtual package
                     Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:3.0) but 1:8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04 is installed
```

Since I haven't been documenting every step as it occurred, here's a list of the commands I've run trying to fix this issue in case it's useful or more revealing than what I've mentioned above:

```
  485  pip list
  486  pip freeze | grep cupy
  487  nvcc --version
  488  conda update cupy
  489  conda install numba cudatoolkit pyculib
  490  conda update cupy
  491  uname -a
  492  lspci | grep -i nvidia
  493  uname -m && cat /etc/*release
  494  gcc --version
  495  uname -r
  496  cat /var/lib/apt/lists/*cuda*Packages | grep "Package:"  
  497  pip --update cupy
  498  pip install cupy --upgrade
  499  pip install cupy --no-cache-dir -vvvv
  500  pip install cupy
  501  nvcc --version
  502  sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
  503  nvcc --version
  504  conda install -c conda-forge cupy
  505  pip freeze
  506  sudo apt-get --purge remove "*cublas*" "*cufft*" "*curand*"  "*cusolver*" "*cusparse*" "*npp*" "*nvjpeg*" "cuda*" "nsight*"
  507  apt-get install -f
  508  sudo apt-get install -f
  509  conda uninstall cupy
  510  conda list
  511  conda list --revisions
  512  conda env list
  513  conda install --revision 11
  514  conda list --revisions
  515  conda install --revision 13
```

## Fixed by uninstalling CUDA and cupy, then reinstalling.

I followed uninstall steps for CUDA listed at the end of their [install instructions](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#ubuntu-installation), along with some other purge commands from another post (I think it was sudo `apt-get --purge remove "*nvidia*"`). I deleted the ~upy and ~upy-6.0.0-py3.7.egg-info folders that were created previously. Then I went through all the install instructions for CUDA again and used conda forge to install cudatoolkit and cupy. Following the recommend cupy instructions on their site didn't work for me, it produced a very long error after failing to build the wheel. The commands that were successful were:

```
conda install -c nvidia cudatoolkit
conda install -c conda-forge cupy
```

Comment: Can you share the contents of the environment? Have you tried all this in new environments?

Answer (score 0):

For me, the

```
conda install -c conda-forge cupy
```

downgraded the cudatoolkit installed with the step before, and to a non-existent cuda version, too.

Comment: This is what he wrote at the end of the question...